# Performance improvement by mirroring database as READ ONLY?

Tags: sql-server, database, mirroring

In our project we have a need to generate reports and dashboards quickly while other users are busy generating transactions involving inserts, updates and deletes. We are using SQL Server 2012 as the database and using .NET for front-end development. We are thinking of making a mirror image of the current READ-WRITE database to another READ ONLY database and using the READ ONLY database for reports and queries while continuing to use the READ-WRITE Database for updating transaction related tables. Is this a viable option ?  Do let me know your thoughts if there are any performance improvements if this is viable and what are the PROS and CONS of implementing this.

Thanks.

Comment: the benefit is that the reporting queries won't lock up the transactional data, and you can add more indexes, or denormalize some tables to make it go faster. I don't think making it read only will have much of an impact. Also, I think the term you want is replication, not mirroring. See: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic539425-291-1.aspx

Comment: Replication, backup/restore, or even AlwaysOn are viable solutions.  What you need to understand is what the acceptable latency is between the two.  That will determine what option you should go with.